# How to access GNOME header in Qt project

Tags: gnome, qt

I'm working on developing a Qt/C++ application for Linux distros which has a module which deals with icon overlays. I need icon overlays exactly like in svn or dropbox. First I'm starting with GNOME environment.

I found that I need to access APIs provided by nautilus, for example for icon overlay, I need to use the API - **nautilus_file_info_add_emblem()** which is part of **nautilus-file-info**

Link - https://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-file-info.html

How do I access the nautilus file managers' headers in my Qt/C++ project ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `*.pro` file,

Then use `INCLUDEPATH += ...` to set header paths,

And `LIBS += ...` to add extra libraries

[See here to learn about qmake flags.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html)

Comment: Yep, I got that. But I'm looking for which lib to add at LIBS & the path to be added at INCLUDEPATH. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Rahul see `pkg-config` for help